# JavaFX - Is it possible to divide a shape into two or more shapes?

Tags: java, javafx, path, shapes

For example, I have this [Path](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html)

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DivideShape extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var path = new Path(new MoveTo(200, 380), new LineTo(0, 300),
            new ArcTo(300, 300, 0, 300, 0, false, true), new LineTo(380,
                    200), new ArcTo(180, 180, 0, 200, 380, false, false));
        path.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(path)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

And I want to divide it into 5 parts (exactly the same as dividing pizza)

This can be done using [Line](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html).

However, this way it will look like 5 objects, but in reality it will still be 1 object.

Is it possible to divide the object into 5 [Paths](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html) so that I don't have to create them all one by one, please?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Of course, when I modify the start method.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var pane = new Pane();
    var moveTo = new MoveTo(200, 380);
    var lineTo = new LineTo(0, 300);
    var arc_big = 300;
    var arc_small = 180;
    for (var deg = 198; deg <= 270; deg += 18) {
        var path = new Path(moveTo, lineTo);
        lineTo = new LineTo(300 + arc_big * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(deg)), 300 + arc_big * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(deg)));
        path.getElements().add(new ArcTo(arc_big, arc_big, 0, lineTo.getX(), lineTo.getY(), false, true));
        var move = new MoveTo(380 + arc_small * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(deg)), 380 + arc_small * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(deg)));
        path.getElements().addAll(new LineTo(move.getX(), move.getY()),
        new ArcTo(arc_small, arc_small, 0, moveTo.getX(), moveTo.getY(), false, false));
        moveTo = move;
        path.setFill(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()));
        pane.getChildren().add(path);
    }
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image]

So I'll create five separate [Paths](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html), but the code is too complicated. That's why I wanted to know if it could be divided (1 Object to 5 Objects), please?

Answer (score 5):

When a code *becomes too* complicated consider refactoring it into short single-responsibility reusable methods:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ConvinienceMethodsExample extends Application {

    private static final double OUTER_RADIUS =300, INNER_RADIUS = 180, ORIGIN_X = 300, ORIGIN_Y = 300;
    private static final double START_ANGLE =20, END_ANGLE = 70, STEP_ANGEL = 10;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group group = new Group();

        for(double angle =  START_ANGLE; angle < END_ANGLE ; angle += STEP_ANGEL ){

            Point2D innerArcStart = getPoint(INNER_RADIUS, angle);
            Point2D innerArcEnd = getPoint(INNER_RADIUS, angle + STEP_ANGEL);
            Point2D outerArcStart = getPoint(OUTER_RADIUS, angle);
            Point2D outerArcEnd = getPoint(OUTER_RADIUS, angle + STEP_ANGEL);
            var path = getPath(innerArcStart, innerArcEnd, outerArcStart, outerArcEnd);
            group.getChildren().add(path);
        }
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(group)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Point2D getPoint(double radius, double angle){

        double x = ORIGIN_X - radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
        double y = ORIGIN_Y - radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
        return new Point2D(x, y);
    }

    private Shape getPath(Point2D innerArcStart, Point2D innerArcEnd, Point2D outerArcStart, Point2D outerArcEnd){
        var path = new Path(
                new MoveTo(innerArcStart.getX(), innerArcStart.getY()),
                new LineTo(outerArcStart.getX(), outerArcStart.getY()), //left line
                new ArcTo(OUTER_RADIUS, OUTER_RADIUS, 0, outerArcEnd.getX(), outerArcEnd.getY(), false, true), //outer arc
                new LineTo(innerArcEnd.getX(),innerArcEnd.getY()), //right line
                new ArcTo(INNER_RADIUS, INNER_RADIUS, 0, innerArcStart.getX(), innerArcStart.getY(), false, false)
                );
        path.setFill(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()));
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. The code is perfect, but I focused so much on this shape that I forgot to turn in "all 4 directions". However, this can be solved easily by changing the variables. (START_ANGLE = 110/200/290, END_ANGLE = 160/250/340). However, there is still the problem that the shape is smaller than the image in question. How do I adjust the variables so that the size is the same, please? Thank you

Comment: The size of the shape is controlled by start and end angles as well as the outer and inner radius. Try, for example setting `OUTER_RADIUS =400, INNER_RADIUS = 100`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Compared to the image in question, the window is smaller and only the inner "side" of the shape touches the edges of the window. But the main thing is that the inner and outer "side" are not in the shape of a circle.

Comment: Here is an [image](https://imgur.com/FJwu7ox) of two shapes. One as in the code posted, and one with `OUTER_RADIUS =400, INNER_RADIUS = 100, ORIGIN_X = 400, ORIGIN_Y = 400`. It does work. You need to fully understand what the code does to be able to modify it to your need.

Comment: Hello, I apologize for the late reply. Even though your code looks simple, much simpler than mine, I still can't figure out how to achieve the same result. So, I'm embarrassed, but what values ​​to enter there? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with Arc object instead of Path 
in this code i've made five arcs of 18 degrees each one and a fade animation to make transparent the path . when the animation ends i remove path from pane children
     `

```
 package dividedshape;

 import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
 import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 import javafx.scene.shape.*;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import javafx.util.Duration;

 public class DivideShape extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  Path path = new Path(new MoveTo(500, 500), new LineTo(0, 500),
            new ArcTo(500, 500, 0, 500, 0, false, true), new LineTo(500, 
    500));
    path.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    Arc arc1 = new Arc(500,500,500,500,90,18);
    arc1.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    arc1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    Arc arc2 = new Arc(500,500,500,500,108,18);
    arc2.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    arc2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    Arc arc3 = new Arc(500,500,500,500,126,18);
    arc3.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc3.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    arc3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    Arc arc4 = new Arc(500,500,500,500,144,18);
    arc4.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc4.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    arc4.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    Arc arc5 = new Arc(500,500,500,500,162,18);
    arc5.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc5.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    arc5.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    Pane pane = new Pane(arc1,arc2,arc3,arc4,arc5,path);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
    primaryStage.show();

    FadeTransition fadePath = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(10), path);
    fadePath.setFromValue(10);
    fadePath.setToValue(0);
    fadePath.play();
    fadePath.setOnFinished(e->{ pane.getChildren().remove(path);});


   }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
     }
    }`
```

[image: result after fade animation]

Comment: Sorry, I gave too simple an example. I have already modified it, now it is necessary to create 5 Paths. I managed to write it, but the code is too complicated, so I didn't mention it at all. Therefore, I wanted to know if there is the opposite procedure - not to create 5 objects, but to create 1 object, which I will divide into 5 objects.

Comment: you may need to implement a sin cosin method

Comment: Of course, I used it and created 5 separate objects, but the code is too complicated. (see **Update** in question)